# Python: Threading/multiprocessing with matplotlib and user input

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I am currently working on a code that will continuous plot data retrieved via serial communication while also allowing for user input, in the form of raw_input, to control the job, such as starting/stopping/clearing the plot and setting the save file names for the data. Currently, I'm trying to do this by having an extra thread that will just read user input and relay it to the program while it continuously plots and saves the data.

Unfortunately, I have run into some errors where commands that are entered during the plotting loop freeze the program for 2 minutes or so, which I believe has to do with matplotlib not being thread safe, where a command entered while the loop is not working with the plotting libraries will lead to a response in 1-2 seconds.

I have attempted switching from threading to the multiprocessing library to try to alleviate the problem to no avail, where the program will not show a plot, leading me to believe the plotting process never starts (the plotting command is the first command in it). I can post the codes or the relevant parts of either program if necessary.

I wanted to know if there was any way around these issues, or if I should start rethinking how I want to program this. Any suggestions on different ways of incorporating user input are welcome too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If matplotlib is not thread-safe, the right thing to do is to serialize all the inputs into matplotlib through a single event [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).  Matplotlib can retrieve items off the queue until the queue is empty, and then process all the new parameters.

Your serial communication code and your raw_input should simply put data on this queue, and not attempt direct communication with matplotlib.

Your matplotlib thread will be doing one of three things:  (1) waiting for new data; (2) retrieving new data and processing it (e.g. appending it to the arrays to be plotted or changing output file names) and staying in this state as long as the queue is not empty, or moving on to state (3) if it is; or (3) invoking matplotlib to do the plotting, then looping back to state (1).

If you are implementing multiple action commands from your raw_input, you can add some auxiliary state variables.  For example, if 'stop' is read from the queue, then you would set a variable that would cause state (3) to skip the plotting and go straight to state (1), and if 'start' is read from the queue, you would reset this variable, and would resume plotting when data is received.

You might think you want to do something fancy like: "if I see data, wait to make sure more is not coming before I start to plot."  This is usually a mistake.  You would have to tune your wait time very carefully, and then would still find times when your plotting never happened because of the timing of the input data.  If you have received data (you are in state 2), and the queue is empty, just plot!  In the time taken to do that, if 4 more data points come in, then you'll plot 4 more next time...